# get value based on another subelement

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON file from which I want to get the value of `health`, which is `up`.
The result should be based on the `__address__`.

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "activeTargets": [
      {
        "discoveredLabels": {
          "__address__": "prometheus.1.de",
          "__metrics_path__": "/federate",
          "__param_match[]": "{job=~\".*\"}",
          "__scheme__": "http",
          "job": "federate"
        },
        "labels": {
          "instance": "prometheus.1.de:80",
          "job": "federate"
        },
        "scrapePool": "federate",
        "scrapeUrl": "http://prometheus.1.de:80/federate?match%5B%5D=%7Bjob%3D~%22.%2A%22%7D",
        "globalUrl": "http://prometheus.1.de:80/federate?match%5B%5D=%7Bjob%3D~%22.%2A%22%7D",
        "lastError": "",
        "lastScrape": "2020-10-13T06:35:59.96463521Z",
        "lastScrapeDuration": 3.339807114,
        "health": "up"
      },
      {
        "discoveredLabels": {
          "__address__": "localhost:9090",
          "__metrics_path__": "/metrics",
          "__scheme__": "http",
          "job": "prometheus"
        },
        "labels": {
          "instance": "localhost:9090",
          "job": "prometheus"
        },
        "scrapePool": "prometheus",
        "scrapeUrl": "http://localhost:9090/metrics",
        "globalUrl": "http://prometheus-2:9090/metrics",
        "lastError": "",
        "lastScrape": "2020-10-13T06:35:53.366524719Z",
        "lastScrapeDuration": 0.005405697,
        "health": "up"
      }
    ],
    "droppedTargets": []
  }
}
```

i tried this:

```
$ cat 1.json | jq -r '.data.activeTargets[] | .health |= map(select(.discoveredLabels.__address__ == "prometheus.1.de"))'
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over string ("up")
```

any tips?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2):

`cat 1.json | jq -r '.data.activeTargets[] | select(.discoveredLabels.__address__ == "prometheus.1.de") | .health'`

Comment: Check this case: you have more than 1 object with `select` filter. The you will take more than one `.health`!

Comment: on my case that one worked. it would have been nice if you could explain it a bit better how that one looks inside that element but gets the element outside..
thank you doubleui

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand: what is inside but gets outside? :)

Comment: '__address__' is inside the discoveredLabels but health is outside of it

Comment: `select` is just a fliter for prev result. So you do not move from `.data.activeTargets[]` array and "dot" in `.health` is still looking in filtered array.